# Issues with JumpList in C#

Tags: c#, jump-list

I am working on a C# application and trying to implement jump lists using the JumpList class from the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar namespace. However, I am encountering the following errors and could use some assistance in resolving them:

```
CS0176: Member 'JumpList.AddToRecent(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead:
```

```
CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to 'string?':
```

```
if (TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported)
{
    // Create a jump list
    JumpList jumpList = JumpList.CreateJumpList();

    // Add recent items
    jumpList.AddToRecent("C:\\Path\\To\\RecentFile.txt");

    // Add custom tasks
    JumpListLink customTask = new JumpListLink(new Uri("C:\\Path\\To\\Executable.exe"), "Custom Task");
    jumpList.AddUserTasks(customTask);

    // Save the jump list
    jumpList.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the "cannot convert"-exception, can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: It is a static function use `JumpList.AddToRecent("C:\\Path\\To\\RecentFile.txt");` (with capital `J`')
https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/master/source/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/Taskbar/JumpList.cs#L256

Comment: @lidqy My error got solved with capital `J` but nothing happened.

Comment: @NumberTwo the static thing using JumpList as a class (and not an instance) should solve the CS0176 error but not the CS1503 ...